# Is it safe to call .ConfigureAwait(false) in finally block?

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-5.0

I have a "rest client" that wraps `HttpClient` and whose methods are async.
Besides other reasons, I need to control signin/signout process with my rest client so that number of sessions is not exceeded.

The rest client implements `IDisposable` and upon disposing the client I need to check if the client is "still signed in" and sign out if it is.
Since doing any kind of external calls in Dispose method is considered bad practice, I have something as following

```
public class MappingsController : RestController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetYears()
    {
        return await ProcessRestCall(async rc => await rc.GetYearsAsync());
    }
}

public class RestController : ApiController
{
    protected async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ProcessRestCall<T>(Func<RestClient, Task<T>> restClientCallback)
    {
        RestClient restClient = null;
        try
        {
            var credentials = GetCredentialsFromRequestHeader();
            if (credentials == null)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Missing credentials from header!");
            }
            var username = credentials["Username"];
            var password = credentials["Password"];

            restClient = new RestClient(username, password);
            var authenticated = await restClient.SignInAsync();
            if (!authenticated)
            {
                return CreateErrorResponseWithRestStatus(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, restClient);
            }
            var result = await restClientCallback(restClient);
            // Following works, but since I need to do it in finally block in case exception happens, perhaps It should be done in finally anyways...
            //await restClient.SignOutAsync(); 
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return CreateErrorResponseWithRestStatus(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, restClient, e);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (restClient != null)
            {
                if (restClient.IsSignedIn)
                {
                    //var signedOutOk = restClient.SignOutAsync();//.Result; //<-- problem - this blocks!!!
                    restClient.SignOutAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); // seems to work, but I am not sure if this is kosher + I can't get return var

                    //Logger.Warn(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, m => m("Client was still signed in! Attempt to to sign out was {0}", signedOutOk ? "successful" : "unsuccessful"));
                }
                restClient.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of `.ConfigureAwait(false)` is a non-issue.  **You aren't awaiting on the task at all.**  Since you don't `await` it, it doesn't matter what `await` is configured to do.

What you're doing is just basic fire and forget (which may or may not be acceptable for you).

You should remove the `ConfigureAwait(false)` no matter what, just because it does nothing and is confusing to the reader.  If it's okay for you to send the request to sign out but not actually sign out, then this is okay.

If you need to ensure that `restClient.Dispose();` isn't called until the sign out request returns, then you have a bit of a...problem.  The problem stems from the fact that the sign out request might be unsuccessful, or much worse, it might not respond at all.  You'd need some way of dealing with that.

You can't use `await` in a `finally` block, but you can more or less mimic its behavior through continuations.  You may need to do something like this:

```
public static async Task DoStuff()
{
    IDisposable disposable = null;
    try { }
    finally
    {
        var task = GenerateTask();
        var continuation = Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(5000))
            .ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                if (task.IsCompleted) //if false we timed out or it threw an exception
                {
                    var result = task.Result;
                    //TODO use result
                }

                disposable.Dispose();
            });
    }
}
```

Note that since you aren't using `await` the task returned from `DoStuff` will indicate that it is "done" as soon as it hits the finally block for the first time; not when the continuation fires and the object is disposed.  That may or may not be acceptable.

Comment: you have correctly identified my need. Before I dispose, I need to check if client is still signed in and if it is, then I need to *at least* attempt to sign out. For example, try to sign out and wait 5 seconds, and then dispose anyway...And additionally capture the return value of the sign out attempt...Very tricky since await cannot be in finally block which is "perfect" for dispose call :)

Comment: @zam6ak You'd essentially have to do exactly what `await` does, but without `await`.  Call `ContinueWith` on the sign out method, pass a cancellation token or use some other mechanism of providing a time out, and then dispose of the client and do...whatever...with the result of the sign out within that continuation.

Comment: What about not removing ConfigureAwait and doing following:`var signOutAwaitable= restClient.SignOutAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                        var signedOutOk = false;
                        signOutAwaitable.GetAwaiter().OnCompleted(() => signedOutOk = signOutAwaitable.GetAwaiter().GetResult());
                        Logger.Warn(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, m => m("Client was still signed in! Attempt to to sign out was {0}", signedOutOk ? "successful" : "unsuccessful"));`

Comment: Seems like the simplest approach would be to await sign out in try {} and in finally do "fire and forget"....

Comment: @zam6ak Once again, you're not awaiting anything so don't bother using `ConfigureAwait`.  Rather than using those methods it's going to be easier to just work on the task directly through `ContinueWith` calls.  As noted in my answer, your code will result in the `Task` returned from the method being completed before the method is really "done".

Comment: @zam6ak If you do that then you'll sign out twice.  Would be better to await the sign out in the `try` and do a fire and forget in `catch`.

Comment: I was using ConfigureAwait so I could get a result back, but I will try your method as well.

Comment: @zam6ak As I've said several times now, `ConfigureAwait` is for configuring `await`.  If you don't `await` then there's no reason to use `ConfigureAwait`.  It's accomplishing nothing positive.

Comment: @zam6ak You'll sign out once in the body of the `try` and again in the `finally`.  On the server side it'll likely ignore any requests once you've signed out, which is why you wouldn't see it.